# gnuplot: I need to plot on x-axis only 2 values

Tags: gnuplot

I use a gnuplot script to make a graph where I have values on x-axis.

```
 #SETUP X AXIS
 set xlabel 'STATION' offset 0,-1.5
 set xtics out 1001,44 rotate by 90  offset 0,-3
 set xrange [min:max]
```

The above works OK with files with ranges of data between "min" and "max" but this time I have a special case with only two values: I want on x-axis only value1 (min) and value2 (max), nothing before, after and in-between.

How can I do that?

I've tried to comment out

```
 #set xtics out 1001,44 rotate by 90  offset 0,-3
```

But I still get values between min and max on x-axis.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Do you want just plot the minimum and maximum value of a datafile/datablock or do you want to have just a xtic for the minimum and a xtic for the maximum value and no other xtics inbetween? Please clarify and add a graph (and tell which points or tics you want or don't want) or add some example datalines.

Comment: I am also not entirely sure, but perhaps you are looking for `plot "filename" using 1:2:xtic(1)`.

Comment: Another guess: could you be looking for `set xtics (value1, value2)`?  I.e. you can specify a list of places to place a tic rather than a start/interval/end recipe.

Comment: Yes, this works! And yes, theozh, I was looking for having just  a xtic for the minimum and a xtic for the maximum value and no other xtics inbetween because for this file I only had 2 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethan suggestion works

```
set xtics (value1, value2)
```

Thank you!